# Adding click to move with path finding to my current 2D Project in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I currently have a 2D scene with a orthographic camera and I can move my player with my WASD keys which is great.  I am wanting to add functionality of click to move as well but I am sort of lost on a approach.  I have read/watched some tutorials and everything seems to revolve around the Nav/Mesh system.

My issue though is that my current scene for the ground and walls have Sprite Renderers and/or BoxColliders on them and I cannot have a Sprite Renderer and a Mesh Renderer on the same GameObject.  Here is a quick screenshot of what I have :

[image]

Now I understand that I can easily create a click to move with a

```
Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
```

and move towards that position with

```
Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

The challenge for me now and the knowledge that I am wanting is if I have something like in the screenshot how can I add some sort of path finding system if I was below the house and clicked above the house that my character would walk around the house to get there?

Do I even need to edit my current sprites for the ground?  I had an idea that I would just create extra GameObjects add a Mesh Filter and Mesh Renderer to it with "None" for the Materials and place them like puzzle pieces around my scene which would represent the areas I would want my player to move.

Is that approach I am thinking viable?  Is it too much?  Is there an easier way?

Comment: Does your character move in discrete, tile based steps or can they move independently of tiles?

Comment: Currently in this project I have it has scripts that make the character move independently via keyboard (WASD) but I wanted to add click to move functionality with path finding.  I really wanted to use the something built in to Unity as it would make sense but I don't get why they provide this whole side of 2D which we can work with but do not provide NavMesh for XY plane.  From the looks of it though people have been asking for this for a couple years.  The only reason I can think of as to why it isn't added fully yet to the XY planes is them making money off A* assets in the store.

Comment: @ThomasHilbert Atm though I am just coding my own A* system which should be enough for this RPG Kit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "NavMeshAgent" to move your player. The "NavMeshAgent" component is attached to a mobile character in the game to allow it to navigate the scene using the NavMesh.

Once you have baked the NavMesh Its easy to use it -

```
navMeshAgent.SetDestination(target);
```

Reference -
[Video Tutorial to create and use nav mesh](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/navigation/nav-meshes), [Unity Script reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.html), [Navigation and Path Finding](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Navigation.html)

Follow these steps to learn how to bake a Nav Mesh -

1. Create a 3D cube and scale it to (20,1,20) to make it floor(also rename it to floor).
2. Create another 3D cube, place it inside the floor and scale it by 5 on Y axis(rename to house).
3. Duplicate the cube from step2 and change its position so it doesn't overlap with other house.
4. Go to window > Navigation. This will open the Navigation panel with object tab selected.
5. SELECT the floor object in hierarchy. And click on "Navigation static" checkbox.
6. A popup will ask to enable navigation static for children, click "Yes".
7. Go to "Bake" tab in navigation panel and click on "bake" button at bottom.
8. You should be able to see the generated Nav Mesh in blue color.

Screenshot for the same - [image]

Comment: Thank you for some direction on my issue Mukesh Saini.  The thing is though I don't have any Mesh Filters or Mesh Renderers yet as my scene originally was for moving with the WASD keys so the only renderer I have is a Sprite Renderer for my ground and my GameObjects and also on top of that for my walls they use collider2D's.  A lot of the tutorials I come across deal with 3D models and they initially put Mesh Filters and Mesh Renderers on them to start with.  Any approach on how I would accomplish this?

Comment: I added another empty GameObject and just added a Mesh Filter and Mesh Renderer to it and use that as a area for my path finding but when I baked it I didn't see the light blue where my character could walk. :(

Comment: @joeyL, I've included steps to generate Nav Mesh.

Comment: Sadly my issue is that my current project is all on XY plane as its 2D and I cannot use XY plane for mesh rather the NavMesh is only used for the XZ plane.  Wish they would implement a NavMesh for 2D.  I found forum post up to 3 years ago with them promising it was coming for 2D.  Thanks for your help Mukesh Saini

Comment: You can use A* Path Finding algorithm for 2D planes https://arongranberg.com/astar/ and http://www.jgallant.com/nodal-pathfinding-in-unity-2d-with-a-in-non-grid-based-games/